Pooling water concerns on screened in patio
I want to screen in my porch and keep the bugs out. I'm using this video as a general guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVhosIZ4hGo&list=WL&index=1&pp=gAQBiAQB
My problem is that I need to manage pooling water when it rains.
Here's a photo of the situation.

The red is where water is supposed to flow out to the front yard. Note the red line up against the wall running parallel to the house. So the water would go down the initial path towards the wall, turn left, and then turn right to go out to the front yard. The blue is where I want to put the bottom plate for screening in the patio.
In the video she just paints her boards, and then uses tap cons to attach them to the concrete.  I'm looking for advice because I believe that what is done in the video is not enough for my situation.
Thanks.

Do you have axcess to extruded aluminium screen framing?  Frames are made using the aluminium and then screwed to the floor and sides and top frame.  The aluminium on the base should not be caulked and any water will seep out in any sloped area.

Extruded aluminium screen parts have the screen channel built in so no additional screen channel is needed. It will not rot as will the wood used in the video.  Usually can be purchased in white or "Bronze"  which is brown. And if there is no budget there are some custom colors available.

@RMDman I didn’t know that was an option I’ll go do some research on it.

I use these types https://www.metroscreenworks.com/fast-track-porch-screening-system/?setCurrencyId=1&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwodC2BhAHEiwAE67hJMlGHVA81AgFEOISstVaB6cpl8hDnz9laFU4STbSumtEvYTsgQzLPBoCgP0QAvD_BwE

@RMDman I think going with an aluminum system is the way to go. Or at least for the bottom. Thank you.

Your problem here is that your uncovered patio area is higher than your covered patio, and water obviously drains downhill.  You'll need to create some kind of dike at the edge of that "step" to keep water away and flowing to the left.  There are rubber spill blocker dikes that may work for you.  Obviously they may be a trip hazard, so hopefully any doors will be on the left side.
